# move each div into the one previous to it

Tags: jquery, html, append

I'm unsure if this is classed as a child and parent div.

```
<div class="container">
<p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="footer"><p>content</p></div>

<div class="container">
<p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="footer"><p>content</p></div>
```

My CMS is putting the footer outside the post container, for each `.footer` I would like to move them into the closest previous `.container`. I hope this makes sense.

```
<div class="container">
<p>content 2</p>

    <div class="footer"><p>content 2</p></div>

</div>
```

My poor attempt looks like this:

```
    $(".container").each(function() {
    $(".project_footer ")
        .appendTo(".container");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) assuming that the footer always comes after the container:

```
$(".footer").each(function() {
    var currentFooter = $(this)
    currentFooter.appendTo(currentFooter.prev());
});
```

[here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/uhJZ8/)

Comment: Bingo! I didn't know about .prev() Thanks @Joseph

Comment: well, if you can "translate the code into a sentence", there's a jQuery function bound to exist somewhere with that function.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
$(".footer").each(function() {
    currentFooter.appendTo($(this).prev());
});
```